# How to rename a file while using "move" in URL in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have an URL like
url = "file:D:/inputFolder?move=D:/outputFolder". we are making this url dynamically.
I want to rename the file while moving, So I made it something like this
url = "file:D:/inputFolder?move=D:/outputFolder&fileName=abc.txt". But I think move and fileName do not work together, it is not renaming.

Is there any alternative to do it? Please remember I want with "move" only.
I cannot use .setHeader(..) also.

Thanks,

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Comment: public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:D:/inputFolder")
         .process(new MyProcessor());
       
}} this moves file. I want something like public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:D:/inputFolder?move=D:/outputFolder&fileName=abc.txt")
         .process(new MyProcessor());}} this is not working.

Comment: Please, edit question.

Comment: Why do you want to rename to a fixed filename abc. That doesnt sound like a real-life use-case. Can you maybe try to explain better. As the move option in Camel can support renaming the file also, but not intended per-see to a single hardcoded name. But you can try with move=outputFolder/abc.txt

Comment: move=outputFolder/abc.txt  is creating a folder with name abc.txt and then transferring the file with same previous file name. The url is created dynamically based on date but while processing I want to add user_id with the file name, So later we can identify who has moved the file. Hence renaming is required.

Comment: Thanks, My original link is something like "file://\\outputFolder\cioms\61db?move=\\outputFolder\cioms\61db\2018/October/30Oct2018\In-Progress&recursive=true&readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=60s&readLockMinLength=0&delay=10000&idempotent=false&antInclude=**/in/**,*\in* "    and in this link I want to add property like "filename =abc.txt". this link is generated dynamically based on dates.

Comment: The question is unclear, please EDIT your question with a sample use case with details (source location, source file name, expected output location, expected output filename, relocation/rename pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible ways to achieve your goal.

1. Use both "consumer" and "producer"

Using this way, you are free to control where and how your destination can be set and has great freedom to control filename with the use of a processor/bean.

```
    from("file:D:/inputFolder")
        .to("file:D:/outputFolder?fileName=abc.txt")
```

2. Use "consumer" only

Using this way, you are treating your work as source data control. This can be use when your file is going to move within same drive. The drawback is the filename rename pattern is limited (refer to [camel file language](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html))

```
    from("file:D:/inputFolder?move=${file:parent}/../outputFolder/abc.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, My original link is something like "file://\\outputFolder\cioms\61db?move=\\outputFolder\cioms\61db\2018/October/30Oct2018\In-Progress&recursive=true&readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=60s&readLockMinLength=0&delay=10000&idempotent=false&antInclude=**/in/**,*\in* "    and in this link I want to add property like "filename =abc.txt". this link is generated dynamically based on dates.

Answer (score 2):

Hy,

as far as I understand you, your trying to move the file in one single uri.
That is not really how camel works.

The idea of camel is to have a "consumer" and a "producer", where the consumer loads data (e.g. your file) and the producer puts the data somewhere (e.g. save the file into a folder)

That being said, here is what worked for me with a java route:

```
from("file:/home/chris/temp/camel/in")
    .to("file:/home/chris/temp/camel/out/?fileName=test.txt");
```

The `from` part configures the folder where camel looks for new files. A few notes on that:

- The file component checks the folder each 0.5 sec for new files. This can be changed with the `delay` parameter
- The option `noop` configures, if the file is being moved or copied. By default it is set to `false`, which means it is moved

In the `to` part you configure, where the file is supposed to be moved. Here you can use the `fileName` parameter to rename the file.
Be careful with this though, because setting an option in the uri directly does make it "static".
What I mean by that is, that the only way of changing the parameter is by completely reconfiguring the route or by restarting it, where neither is something you would want to do normally.

**Note 1:**
Moving all files that are put into one folder into the same file always overrides the previous file by default.
You could, for example, use the `fileExists` parameter to always just append the content of the file: `fileExists=Append` (See [camel file docu](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) for details)

**Note 2:**
There is an option in the file component to not "move" the file, but copy, rename and delete it, which sometimes is necessary, when you want to move it onto a different drive and a simple copy does not work.
Also see the docu for the camel file component for details on that.

**Note 3:**
You can have multiple `to()` statements in the same route to have the file moved to multiple locations.  For example:

```
from("file:/home/chris/temp/camel/in")
    .to("file:/home/chris/temp/camel/out/?fileName=test.txt")
    .to("smtp:....");
```

Hope I could help you and answer you question.
Greets
Chris

Comment: Thanks, My original link is something like "file://\\outputFolder\cioms\61db?move=\\outputFolder\cioms\61db\2018/October/30Oct2018\In-Progress&recursive=true&readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=60s&readLockMinLength=0&delay=10000&idempotent=false&antInclude=**/in/**,*\in* "    and in this link I want to add property like "filename =abc.txt". this link is generated dynamically based on dates.